# Find Decimal numbers which the fraction and main part are seperated by slash instead of period

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm going to put all decimal numbers in a text inside a span tag (`<span>`) but the numbers are not using period as decimal separator, they use slash (`/`)

The sample text is something like this:

There are 12/5 percent of students who...

And I want to convert it to

There are `<span>`12/5`</span>` percent of students who...

Actually I need the regular expression which matches.

Comment: Maybe a typo? You mean convert to: " There are 12.5 percent of students who..."?

Comment: OK, anything, but I want to put them in span tags. :)

Comment: You know man in some languages the decimal separator is slash!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do they use to represent division in an expression involving numbers (with slashes as decimal separators)?

Comment: which languages have slash as a decimal separator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<!/)\d+(?:/\d+)?(?!/)", "<span>$0</span>");
```

It will work with integers and decimals. Numbers like `1/` or `/1` are not allowed, neither is something like `1/2/3`.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!/)    # Assert that the previous character isn't a /
\d+       # Match one or more digits
(?:       # Try to match...
 /\d+     # a /, followed by one or more digits
)?        # ...optionally.
(?!/)     # Assert that the following character isn't a /
```

Comment: very nice! Is it possible to change the pattern in a way that it leaves intact those numbers who have more than one slash (Dates) such as: 01/02/2001 ?

Comment: Is it possible to change the expression in  a way that it accepts the numbers with colon (:) too?

Comment: Try this: `@"(?<!\1)\d+(?:([/:])\d+)*(?!\1)"`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work for you, taking in count that the number will contain a `/`:

```
[\d]+/[\d]+
```

The following code will do the trick:

```
string text = "12/5";
string pattern = @"\b[\d]+/[\d]+\b";
MatchEvaluator m = match => "<span>" + match.Groups[0] + "</match>";
Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m);
```

Comment: Only one, as I said the slash is actually the decimal separator! (.)

Comment: @ehsun7b `\d` will match a `digit`. It means: `One or more digits, then a /, and then one or more digits`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx:

```
\D+((\d+)\/(\d+))\D+
```

Capture groups:

```
\1 12/5
\2 12
\3 5
```

Comment: This fails with numbers at the start or end of the string.